# cannot get a children of div in xpath

Tags: html, xpath, scrapy

I’m brand new to xpath.  I’m using xpath to get a specific element of a web page.

The page has a specific div with an id.  I can get this div with the following:

```
//div[@id=‘theId’]
```

This div also encapsulates several links.  I would like to get the last link.  I am trying to do this with the following, but it doesn’t work:

```
//div[@id='theId’]/a[last()]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe the quotes, are they special in any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
//div[@id='theId']/child::a[last()]
```

Comment: It's the same `xpath` expression but more explicit.

Comment: Ah I was not aware of that. Tested ok for me, but it looks like if that is the case then you are probably right about the quote format.

Comment: Yes. At least yours has (I guess) the quotes fixed and worked for me too with copy & paste.